# Should I submit the app for review again in the app store connect after answer the questions asked?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I submitted my company app to the app store for review. It's only for the company employees, so the app store reject my app stating

```
This item has been rejected for the following reasons:
2.1.0 Performance: App Completeness
```

and a couple of questions were asked in the review.

I answered the question and send the reply in the app review message section.

Do I have to resubmit the app to review again or the app store will automatically reviews it and send the response again?

```
This item has been rejected for the following reasons:
2.1.0 Performance: App Completeness
```

Is there any change needs to be done for the above reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can reply with Screenshots or with video to Apple reviewer, Once after replying you need to click the app to review (send the app to review). If no binary of the app needs to changed then you can send the review with same build.

Change the build only if any code or metadata(like info.plist or adding extra capabilities) changes are done

Answer (score 0):

If you have already replied with justification then there is no need to resubmit the application again.
Once the appeal has been submitted the rejection status will change to in-review state.

You may [refer](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/) for more details about the appstore guidelines and common mistakes.